# Socket FTP in C: authentication gets 530 "Please login with user and pass" with anonymous

Tags: c, sockets, ftp

I'm trying to connect to a server to download an POS (Point of sale) application. For now, I'm trying to make work on the PC to adapt to the POS. (The POS doen't have a FTP API, just socket)

Trying to connect to ftp://ftp.inf.puc-rio.br/ (139.82.16.194). I also tried ftp.dca.fee.unicamp.br with the same result.

I'm using *sys/socket.h*. I'm getting this:

> 220 Bem Vindo ao Servidor do DI / PUC-Rio.
>
> **USER anonymous**
>
> Response: 331 Please specify the password.
>
> **PASS 123**
>
> Response: 530 Please login with USER and PASS

I tried another passowords like email, guest but no sucess.
In **Filezilla** I use the same values (IP, user, password 123 and port 21) and I get this:

> USER anonymous
>
> Response: 331 Please specify the password.
>
> Comando:  PASS ***
>
> Response: 230 Login successful.

Trying to understand why the server don't accept the PASS command.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define SERVER_PORT_ID 21
#define CLIENT_PORT_ID 8015
#define SERVER_HOST_ADDR "139.82.16.194"
/* ftp.dca.fee.unicamp.br */
//ftp://ftp.inf.puc-rio.br/
#define MAXSIZE 256    

main(int argc,char *argv[]){           

    int sockid, newsockid,i,getfile,ack,msg,msg_2,c,len;
    int no_writen,start_xfer, num_blks,num_last_blk;
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr, server_addr;
    FILE *fp;
    char in_buf[MAXSIZE], buffer[MAXSIZE];       


    if ((sockid = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("client: socket error : %d\n", errno); exit(0);
        
    }
    
    printf("client: binding my local socket\n");
    bzero((char *) &my_addr,sizeof(my_addr));
    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(CLIENT_PORT_ID);
    if (bind(sockid ,(struct sockaddr *) &my_addr,sizeof(my_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("client: bind error :%d\n", errno); exit(0);

    }

    setsockopt(sockid,SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, 0, MAXSIZE);

    //Try to connect
    printf("client: starting connect\n");
    bzero((char *) &server_addr,sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVER_HOST_ADDR);
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT_ID);
    if (connect(sockid ,(struct sockaddr *) &server_addr,
    sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("client: connect error :%d\n", errno); exit(0);

    }

//Print the Welcome message
    do{
        memset((void*) buffer,0,MAXSIZE);
        if(read(sockid,buffer,MAXSIZE) < 0) 
        {
            printf("client: read error :%d\n", errno); exit(0);
        }       
        printf("%s \n", buffer);
    }while(strstr(buffer,"220 ") == NULL);

    printf("Mensagem Welcome recebida\n");

//Try to connect

    stpcpy(buffer,"USER anonymous\r\n");
    printf("%s", buffer);
    if(write(sockid,buffer,sizeof(buffer))< 0){
        printf("client: write error :%d\n", errno); exit(0);
    }
    if(read(sockid,buffer,MAXSIZE) < 0)   
    {
        printf("client: read error :%d\n", errno); exit(0);
    }
    printf("%s", buffer);

    memset((void*) buffer,0,MAXSIZE);
    stpcpy(buffer,"PASS 123\r\n");  
    printf("%s", buffer);
    if(write(sockid,buffer,sizeof(buffer))< 0){
        printf("client: write error :%d\n", errno); exit(0);
    }
    memset((void*) buffer,0,MAXSIZE);
    if(read(sockid,buffer,MAXSIZE) < 0) 
    {
        printf("client: read error :%d\n", errno); exit(0);
    }
    printf("%s \n", buffer);

    exit(0);
}
```

The code are not downloading anything. I'm trying to athenticate frist. Some includes and variables are not used because belongs to the FTP application's exemple that have the rest of code to download.

[FTP Authentication](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_FTPControlConnectionEstablishmentUserAuthenticatio-2.htm)

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I don't know C, but it looks like you're sending an empty `PASS` request.

Comment: Please supply example code that compiles. That code is missing a bunch of includes. Also, you are not calling `socket()` before `bind()` so there is no way you are getting to the login. Both `bind` and `connect` would fail.

Comment: Sorry guys. Code is now correct. @AndrewLambert I put a password, but still the same result

Comment: The usual password for an anonymous login is an email address. Are you sure this works with an existing FTP client?

Comment: Use a packet sniffer to see what FileZilla is really sending, then duplicate it in your code.

Comment: @EJP Like I said, I tried email as password too. Using the pass 123 in Filezilla the logon is succesful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most central problem with the code is that the lengths given to `write()` come from `sizeof`. If you change those to calls to `strlen()`, the anonymous login works. Using `sizeof` for the length sends 256 bytes to the server.

At least the one ftp-server I tried this with (vsftpd), did not like the password otherwise. I did not check the RFC to see if it was the length or the zeros that made it clash. For development you might also want to install some ftpd software locally. I think it might be more prudent to experiment against servers you run yourself.

NIT: I dont know what system you are compiling that code on, but on a Linux/Posix system it would require some more includes. I added

```
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

I suggest you compile with either the clang compiler or use the flags *-Wall -Werror -Wextra* to gcc.

I also suggest using `strerror()` or similar instead of just printing the errno, when something fails.

Comment: Yes, strlen() in write solved the problem. I thought this argument was in bytes, so I used sizeof. Thanks! And I appreciate the other tips.

Comment: The argument is indeed in number of bytes, but `sizeof` gives the size of the whole buffer, whereas `strlen()` counts the number of "characters", i.e. bytes, of text before a '\0' (null) character. Giving the size of the whole buffer, when you have only put meaningful data in a small part of it, is not necessary and did not seem to work. If you like the answer, please acknowledge it by voting or accepting on the answer.

Comment: I got it. Thanks again. I already accepted the answer. But I can't vote. (Reputation)

Comment: indeed! `strlen` will slove the problem.